# OLS Heteroskedasticity correction

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares, heteroscedasticity

I have a data and was trying to correct for heteroskedasticity (which is significant as per Breush Pagan test). However, after using the robust command in stata, my standard errors of almost all the variables increase. Shouldn't it be opposite? In class we were taught that after correction for heteroskedasticity, the standard errors decrease. I am kind of confused here. Please help me out.

Comment: Could you explain what the `robust` command is supposed to do?  From its name one would guess it is not modeling heteroscedasticity at all, but rather is likely downweighting unusually large residuals.  As such it is effectively eliminating a small part of the data, in which case one would expect--as a general proposition, if not in the details--standard errors of estimates to increase.

Comment: @whuber I was assuming that to correct for heteroskedasticity we use the command 
reg y x, robust

Comment: I doubt any such command could work, because to account for heteroscedasticity you need a model for it first.  A quick search for the stata docs suggests `reg y x,robust` is invalid: do you perhaps mean `reg y x, vce(robust)`?

Comment: yep, sorry. I meant `reg y x, vce(robust)`